# How to do lists of pairs?

Tags: haskell

So im suposed to do a function that receives a list of pairs and gives the firsts elements of the pair , the problem is that i only know how to write a list of pair if it is only 1 pair

```
primeiros :: [(a,b)] -> [a] 
primeiros (a,b) = undefined
```

but the problem is that i dont know how to write if is more than 1 pair , i tried this :

```
primeiros [(a,b),(as,bs)] = undefined
```

but this obvious wont work because it will only do something if the list has 2 pairs , i want something that works for whatever pairs.

Comment: What types do the pair consist of?

Comment: primeiros :: [(a,b)] -> [a]

Comment: From the `primeiros :: [(a,b)] -> [a]` type signature I guess all you need to do is `primeiros = map fst`

Answer (score 2):

You create a list with the first element like so:

```
primeiros :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
primeiros (x:xs) = [fst x] ++ primeiros xs
```

`fst` returns the first element of a pair, and you can also use `map`:

```
primeiros :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
primerios = map fst
```

Comment: That's horribly inefficient.

Comment: Would the `map` version be more efficient?

Comment: *Far* more efficient, if you use it correctly--you don't compose them; `fst` is the *argument* of `map`. And your understanding of why someone might down vote the question really isn't necessary for this answer.

Comment: I don't think there should be a composition operator at `primeiros = map . first` since you are not feeding the result of `fst` to `map` as first parameter.

Comment: In general `[e] ++ t` is best written as `e : t`. Both have O(1) complexity, but the second one does not create an additional list. Also, in the first solution, you need `primeiros [] = []` for the empty case. The `map fst` solution is more idiomatic, though.

Comment: @chi Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I just saw thought that my first code snippet looked like what the OP tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

## Pairs

You can create a pair like this:

```
Prelude> (42, "Foo")
(42,"Foo")
```

This is a pair where the first element is a number, and the second element is a `String`.

That pair is a both a pair of values, but you can also think of it as a single value.

## List

One way to write a list of values is like this:

```
Prelude> [1,5,2,7,1337]
[1,5,2,7,1337]
```

This is a list of five numbers.

Another way to write the same list is like this:

```
Prelude> 1:5:2:7:1337:[]
[1,5,2,7,1337]
```

---

Now that you know how to write a pair as a single element, and how to write a list of elements, I'm sure you can figure out how to write a list of pairs.